# Is hanging from a bar contraindicated in the case of a shoulder dislocation history with labrum damage?

Tags: exercise, orthopedics, anatomy, shoulder

I have just found a book by John Kirsch "[Shoulder Pain? The Solution & Prevention](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1589096428)" (see also [here](https://www.trainyourselffit.com/shoulder-pain-and-how-to-fix-it/) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCyJkccWWH_RHUvqJuRF3M1Q))  which promotes hanging form a bar with extended arms ("dead hang") as (partial) solution to many shoulder problems. In the comments however some users say that this is contraindicated if you had a shoulder dislocation in the past.

What is the reason for this claim? Does hanging from the bar bring your humerus head in a position where it is likely to dislocate again (because of a damaged labrum).

The answer may be different for anterior, posterior and inferior dislocation history with corresponding labrum damage. I am in particular interested in the posterior case.

As I see it, the "dead hang" position on the contrary seems to be a safe position, because the humerus head is pulled away from the damage labrum.

Another reason I might think of is that not the position itself is unsafe, but the fact that this would mobilize your joints (maybe too much), so they become too mobile which maybe would reduce stability, so that you may dislocate again in another position later.

Note that I am *not* talking about shoulder dislocations that occurred from laxity, *but* about dislocations that occurred because for example an accident (or maybe a seizure in the case of posterior dislocation).